# Second Symfony via Alias on Apache

Tags: apache, symfony

I've developed an webapp which has to be renewed every year. Last year worked fine, I made the changes and created a new database for the new version and installed it on the server in another directory. The DocumentRoot is /srv/webapp/web/ for the current version and an alias is set for /srv/webapp-2013/web into /2013 for the old version.

Now the problem is that it seems Apache is still routing the request for http://my.server/2013/ or http://my.server/2013/login to the current version (I get the Oops 404 error). Only if I open up http://my.server/2013/app.php I get the old webapp. DirectoryIndex is set to app.php

Why is Apache not routing correctly? I don't want to change the routing in Symfony.

Server is Ubuntu 12.04.4 with Apache 2.2.22

Comment: I advise you to take a look at http://capifony.org/ to improve your deployment procedure.

Comment: Try to clear symfony cache

Comment: capifony.org would be overkill for just a yearly release circle. And the cache is cleared, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. I changed the .htaccess for Symfony to enable the RewriteBase to /2013/ and enabled the vhost_alias apache module.